# Разница между декларациями массивов - имя до или после указания размерности в квадратных скобках

Tags: java, массивы

Читаю книгу по java и показано два типа массивов:

```
int [] a;
```

и

```
int a [];
```

В чём разница между первым и вторым массивом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они равноправны, но первый из них лучше соответствует стилю Java. Второй же — наследие языка Си (многие Си-программисты переходили на Java, и для их удобства был оставлен и альтернативный способ). [ИСТОЧНИК](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/massivy-java)

Comment: Не идеал, но +/- понятно

Answer (score 1):

Есть и "гибридный" способ записи, например:

```
int[] a[];
```

Что равносильно

```
int[][] a;
```

Но такое лучше вообще не использовать, ухудшает читаемость, особенно если "трюки" такого вида:

```
int[] a, b[], c[][];
```

Что эквивалентно (в рекомендуемом Java-стиле):

```
int[] a;
int[][] b;
int[][][] c;
```